# onActivityResult() is not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I am new to the Android I have one fragment class when the button click action go to the next activity & returns with some variable return is it possible.

in fragment class

```
checkin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CardAnimation.class);
        getActivity().startActivityForResult(i,222);
    }
});
```

i am trying onActivityResult & OnPermissionResult but it's not working

On activity side

```
printout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     finishactivity(222);
    }
});
```

Comment: post your on activity result code..

Comment: u want result in fragment or in activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(i,222);
```

result will be returned to your activity. If you want to be  returned to fragment, remove **getActivity()** part.

Use this:

```
startActivityForResult(i,222);
```

Also you need to `setResult(RESULT_OK, intent)` for returning at your activity. Then do not forget to call `finish()`

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra("KEY", "DATA"); 
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

Comment: hi then how can i get the return with some variables return

Comment: @AravindV Then could you accept and upvote my answer :)

Comment: sorry i dont have 15 repitations i tried its not accepting

Answer (score 1):

Please try replacing  `finishactivity(222);`  with `setResult(RESULT_OK)`

Your code in the CardAnimation Activity should be replaced as below

```
printout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    finish();

    }
});
```

You will receive a callback first to the onActivityResult() method in your activity file. If you want the call back to reach the OnActivityResult of your fragment you need to call `super.onActivityResult()` in your activity.

Comment: hi , then how can i return with some data in activity to fragment

Comment: The on activityResult() in fragment will be called. i have made a mistake. I am editing the answer.

Comment: k tell me what i have to do

Comment: actually i need one return parameter to fragment that to string how it tell me

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
finishactivity(222);
```

with

```
setResult(RESULT_OK) //or RESULT_CANCEL
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

**Fragemt class:**

```
checkin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CardAnimation.class);
        startActivityForResult(i,222);
    }
});
```

**Activity class:**

```
printout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

       Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
       resultIntent.putExtra("YOUR_KEY", "Your data"); 
       setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
       finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: hi , i need one variable return from the activity then how can i get return values

Comment: Try my updated answer. Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
       resultIntent.putExtra("YOUR_KEY", "Your data"); 
       setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
       finish();